# Зачем здесь stop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

зачем здесь stop()? что он делает

```js
$(function() {

  $('.some_link').on('click', function(e) {
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $('#some_point').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="some_link">button</button>

<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>


<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>


<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>

<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>

<section id="some_point">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae debitis saepe dolorum dignissimos quisquam corporis, ullam animi cupiditate a quis aperiam laudantium, labore exercitationem voluptate ducimus consequuntur illum enim?</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Останавливает анимацию на элементах.
Подробнее можно прочитать тут [Jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: так а для чего тут ее останавливать? не совсем понимаю

Comment: @antonio, чтобы приостановить анимацию, когда повторно нажат `.some_link`